# Method declared but not found in a class object

Tags: python

I just began the long and painful journey in Python Class Objects and try this:

```
class UgcObject:
       
    def __init__(self, strPlateformeOld, strIdOld):
        self.strPlateformeOld = strPlateformeOld
        self.strIdOld = strIdOld
     
    def GetApiUpdatedMetadata(self):    
        if self.strPlateforme == "youtube":        
           return True      
           
    def GetblnUpdatePossible(self):
        return GetApiUpdatedMetadata()
    
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ugc_test = UgcObject("youtube","id")
    print(ugc_test.GetblnUpdatePossible())
```

I got an error message:  `NameError: name 'GetApiUpdatedMetadata' is not defined`
I don't get why considering that I believe the `GetApiUpdatedMetadata` is declared and above the method that calls it.

What did I did wrong?

Comment: You tried to refer to a variable that doesn't exist, instead of an attribute that does.

Comment: You want `self.GetApiUpdatedMetadata()`

Comment: methods defined in a class need an instance of an object. Outside the class that would be `ugc_test.`, inside the class that's the role of `self` argument. Use `return self.GetApiUpdatedMetadata()`

Comment: You should probably work through [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), instead of assuming that Python works the same way C++/Java do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to call another method in the same class it should have `self.` in front of it, and the variable name `self.strPlateforme` is wrong:

```
class UgcObject:
       
    def __init__(self, strPlateformeOld, strIdOld):
        self.strPlateformeOld = strPlateformeOld
        self.strIdOld = strIdOld
     
    def GetApiUpdatedMetadata(self):    
        if self.strPlateformeOld == "youtube":        
            return True      
           
    def GetblnUpdatePossible(self):
        return self.GetApiUpdatedMetadata()
    
   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ugc_test = UgcObject("youtube","id")
    print(ugc_test.GetblnUpdatePossible())
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But there is no self.strPlateforme in my code. Did you mean " self.strPlateformeOld"?